# Absolute value of a sum of non-identically distributed RVs

Tags: probability

Let $X=\left|\sum _{i=1}^n Z_{i} \right|$  where random variables $(\textit{Z${}_{i}$})$ are independent but $not$ identically distributed, and,

$Z_{i} =0$,$+1$ or$-1$, with probability $1-a_i$, $\frac12a_i$ and $\frac12a_i$ respectively, with $0<a_i<1$.

What is  ${E}({X})$?

EDIT: some people have raised concerns about not including background motivation here. This is a generalization of a previous question I posted, [Variance of absolute value sums of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1346855/21373), and both concern a model I am developing for phenotypic pair-wise distances based on a simple quantitative genetic model.

EDIT (cont.): The reason I am interested in $E(X)$ is that ultimately I am looking for $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, which in turn is required to compute the correlation between $X$ and $Y$, for which I already have a lower bound on their covariance, from [Correlation between two sampling RVs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/150188/21373). If solving this is intractable, my thoughts are to use the Gaussian approximation, whereby effectively $X$ is a half-normal distribution.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you know the answer for the related problem where $Z_i$ are iid symmetrical Bernoulli? Do you know the answer here if $a_i \equiv 1/2$? The model is still symmetrical. The zeros just prolong the inevitable. (Maybe look up symmetrical random walk on the positive and negative integers.) –

Comment: @Omri, this question was closed not just for a "*lack of background motivation*", but also for a lack of effort on your part. The additional context that you should include is also "* your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it*".

Comment: OK, thanks for your note. I added some thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @Mike Pierce, could this question be removed from "on hold" please?